# Exporting rhino3dm.File3dm to STL in python

Tags: python, grasshopper, rhino3d

I’m using rhino.compute to calculate a mesh.

How could I convert the 3dm decoded mesh to an STL file?

Currently, I can only save it as a 3dm:

```py
import compute_rhino3d.Grasshopper as gh
import rhino3dm

output = gh.EvaluateDefinition(definition_path, trees)
mesh = output['values'][0]['InnerTree']['{0}'][0]["data"]

mesh = rhino3dm.CommonObject.Decode(json.loads(mesh))
doc = rhino3dm.File3dm()
doc.Objects.AddMesh(mesh)
doc.Write("model.3dm", version=0)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rhino.RhinoDoc.WriteFile` to write to all file types that rhino conventionally supports for exporting.

```py
def ExportStl():
    
    #Path to save File.
    filepath = r"C:\Temp\TestExport.stl"
    
    #Create write options to specify file info.
    write_options = Rhino.FileIO.FileWriteOptions()
    
    #Export all geometry, not just selected geometry.
    write_options.WriteSelectedObjectsOnly = False

    #Write File.
    result = Rhino.RhinoDoc.ActiveDoc.WriteFile(filepath, write_options)

ExportStl()
```

In this case, I'm using the Rhino 'RunPythonScript' command with the open `ActiveDoc` but in your example, you could use `doc.WriteFile(filepath, write_options)` instead.

When you first run this, there is a .stl export dialogue that has export options. This window can be suppressed to the command line with `write_options.SuppressDialogBoxes = True`.

Or you can check the '*Always use these settings. Do not show this dialogue again.*' option and it will not interrupt export in the future.
[image]

Your example suggests you may be working in a headless environment so I'm not sure how these dialogues would be handled in that scenario.